# How to get all .mp3 files(from both media card and device memory) in j2me?

Tags: file, java-me, mp3

Is there anyway to get all .mp3 file listing in j2me like android.
and if not what is the best way to get all mp3 files.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.file.*;

/**
 * @author crazywizard
 */
public class RootMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
    private List list;
    private Command exitCommand;
    private Hashtable allowed_types;

    public RootMIDlet(){
        /* Construct MIDlet */
        //Define the file types of interest here
        allowed_types = new Hashtable();
        allowed_types.put("mp3", "audio/mp3");        
    }

    public void startApp() {
        list = new List("My Files", List.IMPLICIT);
        exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
        list.addCommand(exitCommand);
        list.setCommandListener(this);
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(list);
        getRootList();        
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

    public void getRootList(){
        //Get ALL available filesystem mounts
        Enumeration drives = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        while(drives.hasMoreElements()){
            //Iterate through the drives
            String driveString = drives.nextElement().toString();
            list.append("Searching "+driveString, null);
            getFileList("file:///"+driveString);
        }
    }//--End of getRootList()

    public void getFileList(String path){
        try {
            //Open path
            FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open(path, Connector.READ);
            //Get list of ALL files and dirs
            Enumeration filelist = fc.list();   //Get Hidden files as well --fc.list("*", true);
            while(filelist.hasMoreElements()){
                String filename = (String)filelist.nextElement();                
                FileConnection fc1 = (FileConnection)Connector.open(path+filename, Connector.READ);
                //Check for dirs
                if(fc1.isDirectory()){                    
                    //Apply recursion here
                    getFileList("file://"+fc1.getPath()+filename);  //Note use of *double // instead of triple ///. Adjust accordingly according to phone platform
                }else{
                    //Filter for only allowed types == .mp3
                    String file_type = getFileType(filename).toLowerCase();
                    if(!allowed_types.containsKey(file_type)){
                        //Do Nothing and Pass
                        continue;
                    }
                    list.append(fc1.getPath()+filename, null);
                }
            }
            //Clean resources
            fc.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(new Alert("Error", ioe.toString(), null, AlertType.ERROR));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(new Alert("Error", ex.toString(), null, AlertType.ERROR));
        }
    }

    /* Helper Method */
    private String getFileType(String fileName){
        //Get file extension from fileName
        char ch = '.';
        int index = fileName.lastIndexOf((int)ch);
        return fileName.substring(index+1);
    }//--End of getFileType(String)

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
        if(c == exitCommand){
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
    }
}
```